# Написать правильно вычисление

Tags: java, массивы

как правильно написать if чтобы при таких вот перепадах в массиве (3, -1, 1, -5,) выдавало true? То есть если идет на уменьшение, например, и встретилось число выше предыдущего, а следующее поле ниже этого числа, которое оказалось ыше предыдущего!

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] a = {10, 3, -1, 1, -5, -37};
      boolean g = false;
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
            for (int k=i+1;k < a.length; k++) {
                if ((k!=i && a[k] > a[i]) && (k!=i && a[k+1] > a[i+1]) && (k!=i && a[k+2] > a[i+2])) {
                    g = true; }
        }
      }
      System.out.println(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: зигзаг, что ли?

Comment: Ну да, типа того

Comment: В программировании не бывает  "типа того". Да или нет?

Comment: ДА!!! Именно да!

Comment: Размер зигзага имеет значение?

Comment: Нет, просто если сначала было убывание(возрастание), потом +, и потом сразу минус или же дублированное число, например (-1, -5, -7, -7,-10), то тогда тоже true! Только это важно

Comment: Вы опять? Мне неохота выуживать информацию из комментариев.

Comment: да это я смогу написать уже имея пример, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 3; i++) { 
    if (a[i] > a[i+1]) && (a[i+1] < a[i+2]) && (a[i+2] > a[i+3])) {
      g = true;
      break; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Разреши поинтересоваться, почему длинна массива минус три?

Comment: @Str Потому что в условии есть `a[i+3]`.

Comment: Если возможно было бы обьяснить этот момент подробнее, был бы очень благодарен. Не сокращает ли это выражение длину массива на 3 и не убирает ли оно поле проверки последних трех полей?

Comment: @Str Этот код ничего не меняет в массиве, а только сравнивает его элементы.

Comment: то есть это просто сравнивает каждые 3 следующие поля массива, как я понимаю? Так?

Comment: @Str Кхм, кхм. Да.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, вот чему-то да и научился новому